# how to calculate the transfer rate speed kb/s SOCKETS c#

Tags: c#, file, sockets, tcp

How to calculate the transfer rate speed in kilobyte per second, i used stopwatch but it doesnt work , because it gives me an error about div on zero ( count / 0)

```
    public void sendFile(string filePath)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        try
        {
            int fileSize = (int)file.Length;
            Program.mainForm.MaxProgressBarHandler(fileSize);
            byte[] fileDetial;
            string detail =  file.Name + "," + fileSize.ToString();
            fileDetial = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(detail);
            client.Send(fileDetial);
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fileSize];

            int count;
            int sum = 0;
            file.OpenRead().Read(fileData, 0, fileSize);
            while (sum < fileSize)
            {
                stopWatch.Restart();
                if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                {
                    count = client.Send(fileData, sum, fileSize - sum, SocketFlags.None);
                    Program.mainForm.UpdateProgressBarHandler(count);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = client.Send(fileData, sum, packetSize, SocketFlags.None);
                    Program.mainForm.UpdateProgressBarHandler(count);
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                sum += count;
                Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(((fileSize * 8) / stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(sum + "of" + fileSize + "sent");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sent");
            CloseClient();
        }
    }
```

Please help me =)

Comment: In any case, instead of rolling your own for-loop, you could just use the SendFile method.  That will likely use the TransmitFile Win32API underneath such that you never have to get the buffers out of kernel space. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2.aspx

Comment: Unless it's a hard-coded non-zero constant, you should ALWAYS check your denominator variable for "0" before dividing.

Comment: mr selbie .. i've already checked that link before .. but there's no receiveFile to handle it from the other side and since i dont know how SendFile works and im not gonna receive correctly plus i want to catch the sent bytes and show them in a progressBar .. what do u advice me to do ?

Comment: Socket.SendFile does exactly what your code does. It opens a file, and streams the contents over a TCP socket. You could replace your entire "sendFile" function above with a single call to Socket.SendFile.  You will not have to make a single modification to code that is running on the other host that is receiving the contents.

Comment: thanks alot mr selbie .. i will keep that in my mind :)
but i still dont know how to show the progress of SendFile .. if i used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first part of your question take a look a this [Joel On Software Forum Thread](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.376575.33). It is not specifically .Net related but is directly dealing with transferring a file using TCP.

As for second part, since I do not have your full code, so I am not able to see why your `stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` is equal to zero. My guess is that there was no data to transfer.  You could try doing something like this to avoid the divide by zero error.

```
if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds != 0)
    Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(((fileSize * 8) / stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString());
```

Though I would probably have a 1 second timer and make `sum` a Class scoped variable and update your label every second i.e:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int sum = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
...

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds += 1;
    Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(((sum * 8) / seconds).ToString());
}
```

and reset them when you finish your transfer.

```
....
finally        
    {        
        timer1.Stop();
        sum = 0;
        seconds = 0
        Console.WriteLine("sent");        
        CloseClient();        
    }
```

Comment: @MurHafSoz You are welcome, I hope that was what you were needing.

Comment: thanks alot mr.Mark Hall
actually as you see this method takes only a file path which its going to send .. you dont have to look to the whole code of the program .. maybe because im dividing an integer over a long value which didnt have the chance to get greater than 0 at the time..
i need a way to calculate the file transfer correctly :S

Comment: @MurHafSoz  That is why I suggested a seperate timer. You can use smaller increments than 1 sec. if needed.

Comment: @MurHafSoz Take a look at this [article](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238674-clocking-transfer-rate-c)

Comment: thanks alot i have figured out and solved it the same way.. :)

Comment: can you check this question for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030297/calculate-sending-file-speed-sec-by-taking-the-average-of-10-times-of-getting-s