# calculate sending file speed/sec by taking the average of 5 times of sent bytes

Tags: c#, performance, average, transfer

im trying to calculate the transfer file speed per second using the average
i took the different between the sent bytes **sum** and the **prevSum** 5 times per second

does the code below give me the correct speed?

should i change the rate array size ?

or should i change Thread.Sleep(value) ?
im so confused because each time a change a little thing the speed value changes.. what's the correct solution for that ??

```
    static long prevSum = 0;
    static long[] rate = new long[5];
    private static void SpeedPerSec(object o)
    {
        fileProgress fP = (fileProgress)o; //get the form conrtols
        while (busy)    // while sending file is active
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rate.Length; i++)
            {
                //diff between the sent bytes and prev sent bytes
                rate[i] = (sum - prevSum);
                Thread.Sleep(1000/rate.Length);
            }
            prevSum = sum;
            fP.RateLabel(Convert.ToInt64(rate.Average()));   
            //print the trasnfer rate which take a long value .. it just print the value in MB or KB string
        }
    }
```

here is the sendFile Code :

```
    public static bool busy = false;
    public static Socket client;
    public static int packetSize = 1024*8;
    public static int count = 0;
    public static long fileSize;
    public static long sum = 0;
public static void sendFile(string filePath)
    {
        // run the progres Form
        Thread thFP = new Thread(fpRUN);
        fileProgress fP = new fileProgress("Sending...");
        thFP.Start(fP);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        byte[] fileData;
        try
        {
            //sending file name and file size to the server
            busy = true;
            fileSize = fs.Length;
            byte[] fileDetial = null;
            string detail =  fileName + "," + fileSize.ToString();
            fileDetial = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(detail);
            client.Send(fileDetial);

            //sending file data to the server

            fileData = new byte[packetSize];
            count = 0;
            sum = 0;

            Thread thSpeed = new Thread(SpeedAndTimeLeft); //*here the thread of SPEED per second method
            thSpeed.Start(fP);
            fP.SizeLabel(fileSize);                     // tell the form the file size
            Thread thClock = new Thread(fP.clock);
            thClock.Start();
            while (sum < fileSize)
            {
                fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fs.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                count = client.Send(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                sum += count;
                fP.ProgressBarFileHandler(sum,fileSize);        //progressbar value
                fP.SentLabel(sum, fileSize);                    //tell the form how much sent                }
        }
        finally
        {
            busy = false;
            fs.Close();
            fileData = null;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} sent successfully", fileName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: sum is neither defined nor a value is assigned to it in your code snippet

Comment: Note that prevSum is not reinitialised each time the 'SpeedPerSec' method is called.
Are you sure that 'rate' is a rate and not just the number of bytes transferred?
I think you will need to give more details of what you are trying to do before someone can help.

Comment: @JAN sum is static long value which is the current sent bytes.

Comment: @gt the SpeedPerSec called once .. within a thread .. prevSum is the sum of the last sent bytes .. the sum is the current sent bytes .. rate is the diff between them

Comment: As I've said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029218/calculate-speed-per-sec-and-time-left-of-sending-a-file-using-sockets-tcp-c-shar/9029334#9029334 there is no "right" code for "show current transfer speed in a way that is nice to look at". Your previous code was not producing "nice to look at" result with 1 second intervals, I doubt you get nicer results with smaller intervals - your call.

Comment: Personally I would compute the average speed for the entire download. The average will then smooth out the longer the download.
If they are longer you can implement a sliding window as was mentioned in your answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using the long[] rate variable... If you want to calculate the transfer rate and update it each second you should store the current fileSize in a variable, and then after the sleep see the new fileSize. Then substract the previous fileSieze from the new one and you have the transfer rate for the last second (the live transfer rate). For the general transfer rate you should calculate it by taking a time-stamp when the download/upload started, and then, after each sleep calculate the rate by dividing the current fileSize with the total seconds passed so far.

Comment: fileSize is constant .. you want me to initialize a variable which hold fileSize - sum(sent bytes) ?? i don't think that this make sense!
long[] rate to get avg of sent bytes per sec .. this's to avoid increasing and decreasing speed ex:(30MB/sec then 5MB/sec then  25MB/sec then 4MB/sec)

Comment: You said "file-speed" and didn't mention if you where doing an upload or a download. Anyway, if you are doing an upload then keeping a count of the total sent bytes will be enough. Then after each sleep, dividing by the total seconds passed so far will give you the overall transfer rate (you don't have to check the transfer rate 10 times per second, but just when you update it).

Comment: im sorry i forgot to say that the application is about .. SENDING FILE USING TCP SOCKETS C# from client to server..
im using now stopwatch and checking while sending file.. if the Elapsed.Seconds==1 .. to print sum-prevSum then reset the stopwatch.. and it works but the value still go up and down :(

Comment: i updated the code.. i hope if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the average every time (which can become slow, if your rates array becomes very large), you can calculate it this way.

consider your rates to be these, for the sake of this example

```
long[] rates = new long[] { 5, 1, 3,4 ,2 ,5, 1};
```

you can calculate the average on each step like this:

```
double currentAverage = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rates.Length; i++)
{
   long currentRate = rates[i];
   int iteration = i + 1;
   currentAverage = (currentAverage * i + currentRate) / iteration;
}
```

Then just wait a second for each rate sample.

Comment: what does this code do ?? is it just instead of rate.Average(); ??
i dont think that would make any difference !!